# ¿Alguno sabe cómo se llama este efecto y si es posible hacerlo en canva?

Tags: canvas

Estoy intentando hacer una animación igual a la que aparece en el link en la parte de arriba de la página donde aparecen las cifras económicas y van variando, mi pregunta es si alguno sabe como se llama ese efecto para buscar un tutorial de como hacerlo o si alguno sabe si es posible hacerlo en canva me ayudaría mucho, he buscado pero no he tenido éxito ya que no sé como se llama el efecto.

Link de la página: https://www.larepublica.co/indicadores-economicos/mercado-cambiario/dolar

Comment: Creo que se llama `Marquee`, Antes había un tah HTML que hacia el efecto solo https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTML/Element/marquee, Además puedes buscar en este mismo sitio por "Marquee" y te van a aparecer varias preguntas que tienen ejemplos

Comment: Voto por cerrar esta pregunta porque está fuera del tema de SO

Comment: a que te refieres con canva? hay algunos frameworks web que usan un objeto Canva.